# Incorrect new Uri(base, relative) behaviour in .NET

Tags: .net, constructor, uri

When you create a new Uri like this:

```
New Uri(New Uri("http://example.com/test.php"),"?x=y")
```

it returns:

```
http://example.com/?x=y
```

It was supposed to return:

```
http://example.com/test.php?x=y
```

according to the every major browser out there (*I'm not quite sure what RFC says though*).

Is this is a bug or is there any other function out there which behaves correctly, also what's the best way to fix it without reinventing the wheel?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it looks like a bug to me. In particular, I would suggest that when you report this on [Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com) you refer to [RFC 1808](http://net_loc), in particular section 4 step 5, and section 5.1 with this example:

```
Base: http://a/b/c/d;p?q#f
Relative: ?y
Absolute: http://a/b/c/d;p?y
```

Not sure about the best way to fix it, I'm afraid :(

Comment: bummer :) Thanks for pointing to correct RFC. I'll do some dodgy fix.